# HTML Table Column Placement

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

I am trying to correctly display my table.
The problem that I am currently having is that the table columns don't stack to the right as a normal table would.

My current output is:

```
Date A
   X
   Y
   Z
Date B
   X
   Y
   Z
```

What I want to do is for it to display like this

```
Date A  Date B
   X      X
   Y      Y
   Z      Z
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
   <table style="float: left;">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
         <tr>
            <th>
               <?php echo $dateArray[$i]; ?>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <?php foreach ($data['timeData'] as $timeTable): ?>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                     <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" id="<?= $timeTable['time_id'];?>" name="time"
                                                   value="<?= $timeTable['time_id'];?> "
                                                   autocomplete="off"><?= $timeTable['time_hour'];?>
                        <input hidden id="<?= $dateArray[$i];?>" name="date[]"
                                          value="<?= $dateArray[$i];?>">
                     </label>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endfor ?>
   </table>
</div>
```

Here is my date Array

```
$dateArray = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
      $dateArray[$i] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$i day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))));
   }
```

Comment: can you show us `$dateArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <table style="float: left;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
        <th>
          <?php echo $dateArray[$i]; ?>
        </th>
        <?php endfor ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($data['timeData'] as $timeTable): ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                               <input type="radio" id="<?= $timeTable['time_id'];?>" name="time"
                                                       value="<?= $timeTable['time_id'];?> "
                                                       autocomplete="off"><?= $timeTable['time_hour'];?>
                               <input hidden id="<?= $dateArray[$i];?>" name="date[]"
                                              value="<?= $dateArray[$i];?>">
                            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <?php endfor ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a loop with a single td...

Put the second td inside the foreach

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Inside your loop has a single td if you want two columns you need the second td... can you show the $dateArray?